# Plotting combined column charts in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, pivot-table

I have data like as shown below in csv file for 3 terms such as A, B, C.

I am trying to plot them using a column chart.

[image]

Basically what my data indicates (ex: Terms A) is out of 200 items, 150 belongs to the MP category and 50 belongs to the UMP category.

So orange and grey should be within a blue color. It shouldn't be stacked one on top of another.

So, my graph should only have two colors because Total (200) should be overwritten by MP (150) and UMP (50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the Terms column, hold Ctrl, then select the MP and UMP columns. Then create the chart. Like this:

[image]

To plot a total and simulate two bars being "inside" another bar in a stacked bar chart, create a new column which subtracts the sum of MP and UMP from Total and plot that as another series, using the same method shown in the gif.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Upvoted. This will work only for the the example that I gave. It may not work when  Let's say we now have Total as `210` and `MP is 150` and `UMP is 40`. How will you plot  `MP` and `UMP` within `Total`

Comment: In the above case, there should be 3 colors..

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: If you don't want to specifically show the total, except as the sum of plotted data, then you don't want to include it in the chart data.